# Create a DBF and FPT file using Visual FoxPro 9.0

Tags: foxpro

I'm trying to create database files using Visual FoxPro OLE DB driver 9.0. The code below generates the .DBF file but I was assuming that it should create a .FPT memo file as well which it doesn't. Please advise as what is missing in the code.

```
`string connectionString = @"Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=C:\Temp;Extended Properties = FoxPro 9.0";
        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                connection.Open();

                command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE TestTest (Id Integer, Name Varchar(100))";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VARCHAR fields don't result in a .FPT file being created.  Only the field types Memo, Blob and General (M, W and G respectively) will; they are truly variable-size fields.   Varchar is still considered a fixed-width type in that the maximum size is physically present in every record.

Comment: thank you for replying. It did generate a .FPT file when i created a column with a "General" type. thanks again!

Comment: General field type is intended for binary data storing. If you need to store text data, then you should use Memo field type.